# scala map function of map vs. list

Tags: scala

Snippet 1:

```
val l = List(1,2,43,4)
l.map(i => i *2)
```

Snippet 2:

```
val s = "dsadadaqer12"
val g = s.groupBy(c=>c)
g.map  ( {case (c,s) => (c,s.length)})
```

In snippet #2, the syntax different than #1 , i.e. curly braces required -- why?
I thought the following would compile, but it does not:

```
g.map ( (c,s) => (c,s.length))
```

Can someone explain why?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

The difference between the two is - the latter uses **Pattern Matching** and the former doesn't.

The syntax `g.map({case (c,s) => (c,s.length)})` is just syntax sugar for:

```
g.map(v => v match { case (c,s) => (c,s.length) })
```

Which means: we name the input argument of our anonymous function `v`, and then in the function *body* we match it to a tuple `(c,s)`. Since this is so useful, Scala provides the shorthand version you used.

Of course - this doesn't really have anything to do with whether you use a Map or a List - consider all the following possibilities:

```
scala> val l = List(1,2,43,4)
l: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 43, 4)

scala> l.map({ case i => i*2 })
res0: List[Int] = List(2, 4, 86, 8)

scala> val l2 = List((1,2), (3,4))
l2: List[(Int, Int)] = List((1,2), (3,4))

scala> l2.map({ case (i, j) => i*j })
res1: List[Int] = List(2, 12)

scala> val g = Map(1 -> 2, 3 -> 4)
g: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Int] = Map(1 -> 2, 3 -> 4)

scala> g.map(t => t._1 * t._2)
res2: scala.collection.immutable.Iterable[Int] = List(2, 12)
```

Both Map and List can use both syntax options, depending mostly on what you actually want to do.

Comment: More syntax sugar is also possible : `g.map{case (c, s) => (c, s.length)}`

Answer (score 1):

1- `g.map{case (c,s) => (c,s.length)}`

2- `g.map((c,s) => (c,s.length))`

The `map` method pulls a single argument, a 2-tuple, from the `g` collection.  The 1st example compiles because the `case` statement uses pattern matching to extract the tuple's elements whereas the 2nd example doesn't and it won't compile. For that you'd have to do something like: `g.map(t => (t._1, t._2.length))`

As for the parenthesis vs. curly braces: braces have always been required for "partial functions," which is what that `case` statement is.  You can use either braces or parens for anonymous functions (i.e. `x => ...`) although you are required to use braces if the function is more than a single line (i.e. has a carriage-return).

I read somewhere that this parens/braces distinction might be relaxed but I don't know if that's going to happen any time soon.